# How can I add a progress bar/status when creating a vector store with langchain?

Tags: python, progress-bar, langchain, faiss

Creating a vector store with the Python library [langchain](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain) may take a while. How can I add a progress bar?

---

Example of code where a vector store is created with langchain:

```
import pprint
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.docstore.document import Document

model = "sentence-transformers/multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1"
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name = model)

def main():
    doc1 = Document(page_content="The sky is blue.",    metadata={"document_id": "10"})
    doc2 = Document(page_content="The forest is green", metadata={"document_id": "62"})
    docs = []
    docs.append(doc1)
    docs.append(doc2)

    for doc in docs:
        doc.metadata['summary'] = 'hello'

    pprint.pprint(docs)
    db = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embeddings)
    db.save_local("faiss_index")
    new_db = FAISS.load_local("faiss_index", embeddings)

    query = "Which color is the sky?"
    docs = new_db.similarity_search_with_score(query)
    print('Retrieved docs:', docs)
    print('Metadata of the most relevant document:', docs[0][0].metadata)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Tested with Python 3.11 with:

```
pip install langchain==0.1.1 langchain_openai==0.0.2.post1 sentence-transformers==2.2.2 langchain_community==0.0.13 faiss-cpu==1.7.4
```

The vector store is created with `db = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embeddings)`.

Comment: the progress bar needs to operate in a loop that has an ending. so, for example a `for loop`.  There is no looping or repeating in the given code, so what is the progress measured against ?

Comment: unless the `langchain` module provides this, the best you could do it create a timer. `n` seconds completed out of "expected" `y` seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Langchain does not natively support any progress bar for this at the moment with release of 1.0.0

I also had similar case, so instead of sending all the documents, I send independent document for ingestion and tracked progress at my end. This was helpful for me.

You can do the ingestion in the following way

```
    with tqdm(total=len(docs), desc="Ingesting documents") as pbar:
        for d in docs:
            if db:
                db.add_documents([d])
            else:
                db = FAISS.from_documents([d], embeddings)
            pbar.update(1)
```

From what I checked from langchain code https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/libs/core/langchain_core/retrievers.py#L31 they are making call to `add_texts` as well, so no major operation is being performed here other than parsing.

I had simple documents, and I didn't observe much difference. Probably others who has tried on huge documents can add if it adds latency in their usecase.

Below is your updated code

```
import pprint
from tqdm import tqdm
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.docstore.document import Document

model = "sentence-transformers/multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1"
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name = model)

def main():
    doc1 = Document(page_content="The sky is blue.",    metadata={"document_id": "10"})
    doc2 = Document(page_content="The forest is green", metadata={"document_id": "62"})
    docs = []
    docs.append(doc1)
    docs.append(doc2)

    for doc in docs:
        doc.metadata['summary'] = 'hello'

    db = None
    with tqdm(total=len(docs), desc="Ingesting documents") as pbar:
        for d in docs:
            if db:
                db.add_documents([d])
            else:
                db = FAISS.from_documents([d], embeddings)
            pbar.update(1)  

    # pprint.pprint(docs)
    # db = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embeddings)
    db.save_local("faiss_index")
    new_db = FAISS.load_local("faiss_index", embeddings)

    query = "Which color is the sky?"
    docs = new_db.similarity_search_with_score(query)
    print('Retrieved docs:', docs)
    print('Metadata of the most relevant document:', docs[0][0].metadata)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```